# Density of squares of radial eigenfunctions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, eigenvector, laplacian

The eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator on the disc can be written in polar coordinates as $f(r,\theta)=R_{nk}(r)e^{ik\theta}$, where $k\in\mathbb Z$ and $n\in\mathbb N$ and the radial function is $R_{nk}(r)=J_k(\lambda_{nk}r)$.
Here $J_k$ is the Bessel function and the numbers $\lambda_{nk}$ are chosen so that $R$ has the correct boundary conditions at $r=1$.
I am interested in Neumann eigenfunctions, but answers with Dirichlet conditions would also be interesting, as they would certainly help me forward.

The radial eigenfunctions are dense in the following sense:
Fix any $k\in\mathbb Z$.
If a continuous function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $\int_0^1R_{nk}(r)g(r)dr=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, then $g=0$.
In fact, with suitable scaling and weighted measure, the radial eigenfunctions $R_{nk}$ form an orthonormal basis for an $L^2$ space over the interval $(0,1)$ for any fixed $k$.

**Question:**
Is the same true for the squared eigenfunctions?
That is, fix any $k\in\mathbb Z$.
If a continuous function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $\int_0^1R_{nk}(r)^{\color{red}{2}}g(r)dr=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, then is $g=0$?

This is not true for the Neumann (or Dirichlet) eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on the interval $[-1,1]$.
The squared eigenfunctions are all even, so any non-trivial odd function $g$ will be a counterexample.
Asymptotically ($k$ fixed, $n\to\infty$) the functions $R_{nk}$ look like sines and cosines, but this does not prove that such a counterexample $g$ would exist for my question.

Based on computations and heuristics, I have a reason to believe that the answer to my question is indeed positive for $k=0$, but that line of thought does not extend to $k\neq0$.
I had trouble finding a good approach for this question with my colleagues, but perhaps someone here knows better?